# Multiple variables from file inside AWK

Tags: bash, loops, unix, awk

I have a file named `users.txt` that contain a list of users in this format:

```
bob
john
alex
tom
```

I need to run this AWK statement and use each of those names as patterns and output to a file

```
awk '/PATTERN/{x=NR+6}(NR<=x){print}' input.txt >> output.txt
```

How do I make AWK loop through each name and use them as search patterns?

Example input file:

```
bob@servername
10/09/2018 19:11:19
50152 command issued.

  weid: A1Pz64385236
  job_name: xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx
  command: fff-fff-fff-fff-
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
alex@servername
10/09/2018 16:33:55
50152 command issued.

  weid: A1Pz64385236
  job_name: xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx
  command: fff-fff-fff-fff-
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
doug@servername
10/09/2018 13:22:66
50152 command issued.

  weid: A1Pz64385236
  job_name: xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx
  command: fff-fff-fff-fff-
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::`
```

Output should be like this, only with users which are in the users.txt file (there are a lot more users in the input file which I don't want to see)

```
bob@servername
10/09/2018 19:11:19
50152 command issued.

  weid: A1Pz64385236
  job_name: xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx
  command: fff-fff-fff-fff
```

Comment: Do you have to use `awk`? This looks like a job for `grep -f users.txt input.txt`.

Comment: Or `grep -F -f users.txt -A 6 input.txt`

Comment: @Barmar I need to find each pattern and once that pattern is found to print the pattern and the next 6 lines. From what I can tell AWK is the best solution for this unless you can show me otherwise.

Comment: Isn't that what the `-A 6` option to `grep` does? You're really making this harder than it needs to be.

Comment: @Barmar grep: illegal option -- F

SunOS  5.10 Generic_150400-48 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V490

Comment: Use `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` to get POSIX syntax, or use `fgrep` instead of `grep -F`.

Comment: How can an experienced Solaris user not know that you have to use `/usr/xpg4` to get standard syntax for utilities, instead of the old BSD versions?

Comment: @Barmar 


`/usr/xpg4/bin/grep: illegal option -- A
Usage:  grep [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] pattern_list [file ...]
        grep -F [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvx] pattern_list [file ...]
        grep -F [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvx] [-e pattern_list]... [-f pattern_file]... [file...]`
Same with fgrep:
`fgrep: illegal option -- A
usage: fgrep [ -bchilnsvx ] [ -e exp ] [ -f file ] [ strings ] [ file ] ...`

Comment: Sorry about that. `-A` is a GNU extension. Can you install GNU grep?

Comment: I'm just a regular user on this server and cannot install anything, have to use whatever the company installed.

Comment: @PFD, could you please post samples for `input.txt` and expected output too in your post for better understanding of your problem too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 added sample input file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While reading the first file, append each line to a pattern string, separating them with `|`. Then when processing the second file test the line against the pattern.

```
awk 'NR==FNR { pattern = pattern (pattern ? "|" : "") $0; next }
     $0 ~ pattern { x = FNR + 6 }
     FNR <= x' users.txt input.txt
```

I tested this on Mac OS High Sierra and Debian Linux with your sample files, the result was:

```
bob@servername
10/09/2018 19:11:19
50152 command issued.

  weid: A1Pz64385236
  job_name: xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx
  command: fff-fff-fff-fff-
alex@servername
10/09/2018 16:33:55
50152 command issued.

  weid: A1Pz64385236
  job_name: xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx
  command: fff-fff-fff-fff-
```

Comment: I get syntax error, copy pasted your exact script: `awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 2
awk: bailing out near line 2
`

Comment: It works fine for me on Mac OS. I can't test on Solaris.

Comment: My previous version expected the pattern to match a whole line, I removed the regexp anchors. But that means `alex` will match `alexis`, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use grep too:

```
grep input -wf users -A 6
```

This will match the names from the users file to the input file and print 6 lines following the match. With the `w` flag grep will only match complete words, you can leave it out depending on your needs.

If your grep does not support `-A`, this may work:

```
grep input -wf users -n | cut -d: -f1 | xargs -n 1 -I {} sed -n "{},/^::*$/ p" input
```

or this:

```
grep input -wf users | xargs -n 1 -I {} sed -n "/{}/,/^::*$/ p" input
```